# Future calls called in chronological order?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I be sure future calls -all- launched with Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:0) will be executed in strictly launching chronological order, placed in a first-in-first-out queue?
Or the execution stack can be messed up, mixed up (after all, delay 0 seconds execution means "execute it as soon as possibile" and it applies to every single queued execution)?

In case of chronological order I should be sure if I do a new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:0) then it will be the very last one executed if no other delayed execution is requested.

Comment: To my opinion, you can not rely on "chronological order" for the delayed actions, especially not for 0 seconds delays.

Comment: If you like fifo, then code fifo ...

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74580710/