# Dart : what happens when two or more tasks are waiting on the same Future

Tags: dart

In Dart, when two or more tasks are waiting on the same Future, when the Future completes, do the tasks get notified/run in the order that they did the await  i.e. the first to do an await is the first to run.

Is this code guaranteed to output 2

```
int res = 0;

Future<void> foo1 () async
{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  res = 2;
}


void main() async
{
  await foo1();
  print(res);
}
```

and what about this code, slightly less obvious

```
int res = 0;

Future<void> foo1 () async
{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
}


Future<void> foo2 (Future<void> f1) async
{
  await f1;
  res = 2;
}

Future<void> foo3 (Future<void> f1) async
{
  await f1;
  res = 3;
}


void main() async
{
  res = 0;
  
  Future<void> f1 = foo1();
  foo3(f1);
  foo2(f1);
  await f1;
  print(res);
}
```

Comment: Yes, after the foo1 function finished, the print statement in main method will continue.

Comment: There are two awaits are waiting on the same future.  How do you know which one "runs" first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no guarantee* that the callbacks get called in the order they were added.

The `dart:async` library code *tries* to call the callbacks in that order, but it's best-effort only. There are cases, typically where one callback is added before the future is completed, and the other is added after, where it's possible to get called in a different order, because they are handled by different code paths.

It's not easy to trigger those cases, the timing has to be just right, but it is possible.

In the example here, there are three awaits on the `f1` future. It's *most likely* that the printed value will be `2` (because nothing fancy is happening), but both `3` and `0` are allowed results.

Answer (score 0):

Code printed 2.

```
int res = 0;

Future<void> foo1() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('foo1 method res 1: $res');
  res = 2;
  print('foo1 method res 2: $res');
}

void main() async {
  await foo1();
  print('last res: $res');
}
```

‍ Code Test Output

```
foo1 method res 1: 0
foo1 method res 2: 2
last res: 2
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be 2?  If so, how do you know?

Comment: @Alpha I updated test code.
Insert 2 to res after await Futrue.delayed method.
Happy Coding 